# Applying a directive from a result returned from a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="message | myFilter"></div> <!-- it does not work -->
<img data-my-directive src="xxx.jpg" alt="some captions"/> <!-- it works -->


angular.module('core').filter('myFilter', ['jQuery',
  function ($) {
    return function (message) {
      var $img = $('<img data-my-directive/>'):
      $img.attr({src : 'xxx.jpg', alt : message});
      return $('<div/>').append($img).html();
    }
  }
]);

angular.module('core').directive('myDirective', [
  function () {
    return {
      restrict : 'A',
      link : function (scope, $element, attrs) {
        $element.someJQueryPlugin();
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

From the above example, I cannot get the first `<img/>` works with `myDirective` if it is attached from the filter, while the second `<img/>` works normally since it originally came from the template file.

Any workaround to get the second `<img/>` works as well?

Please do not ask why I have to make the `<img/>` in this way, it is just an example.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` isn't intended to interpolate angular directives, just raw html. There are numerous other related posts about this with workarounds. If it was me I would use my own directive instead then you can $compile yourself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @charlietfl for suggesting the `$compile` service, this is my solution:

```
<div data-additional-directive data-message="message"></div>

angular.module('core').directive('additionalDirective', ['$compile', '$filter',
  function () {
    return {
      restrict : 'A',
      scope : {
        message : '='
      },
      link : function (scope, $element, attrs) {
        var template = $filter('myFilter')(scope.message);
        $element.html(template);
        $compile($element.contents())(scope);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

I don't know whether it is the best practice in using the directive, but at least it works

I will be appreciated if anyone has better answers!